# Not able to import Mean Absolute percentage error from sklearn.metrics

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am getting error while importing mean absolute percentage error from `sklearn.metrics`:

```
Cannot import name 'mean_absolute_percentage_error' from sklearn.metrics
```

I am using sklearn version 0.23.1

Comment: 0.24 version is not available in anaconda, is there any otherway to update the scikit learn version.

Comment: Anaconda now has many versions above 0.23.2 available.

Answer (score 2):

[mean_absolute_percentage_error](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error.html#sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_percentage_error) **is new in version 0.24**. So you need to update your sklearn version either you can implement it on your own.

[Here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4773f3e39/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py#L197) is the source if you want to implement it yourself.

Comment: Anaconda has version available till 0.23.2 only...is there any other way to update scikit learn?

Comment: Anaconda now has many versions above 0.23.2 available.